# Checking a function result for null values

Tags: c#, .net, null-coalescing-operator

In his answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788466/what-is-the-proper-way-to-check-for-null-values), BlackBear suggested replacing

```
 string y = Session["key"] == null ? "none" : Session["key"].ToString();
```

with

```
 string y = (Session["key"] ?? "none").ToString();
```

This works great if `Session["key"]` is a string value, but what if I want to do this with an object?  For example, I could do this:

```
 string y = GetMyObject() == null ? "none" : GetMyObject().ToString();
```

But what if I don't want to evaluate `GetMyObject()` twice?  Is my only choice to store the results in a variable, then check that variable for null?

```
 var x = GetMyObject();
 string y = (x == null) ? "none" : x.ToString();
```

---

Edit: This is all theoretical - I've run into it before, but I don't have a specific example in front of me right now.  That being said, here's an example class.

```
class MyObject
{
   private MyObject() { }
   public MyObject GetMyObject() { return new MyObject(); }
   public override string ToString() { return "A String"; }
}
```

If I do `string y = (GetMyObject() ?? "none").ToString();`, I get

> Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'MyObject' and 'string'".

Ideally, I'd be able to do

```
 string y = GetMyObject().ToString() ?? "none";
```

and have it work even if GetMyObject() is null.  Basically null-coalescing operator acting as a self-contained `try {} catch (NullReferenceException) {}`.  I know I *can't*, but that would be the ideal.

Comment: You've answered your question yourself

Comment: Without seeing GetMyObject(), sounds like you are on the right track.  You have to bring MyObject into memory at some point, no sense in doing it twice.

Comment: Hmm...  with what type of object does `string y = (Session["key"] ?? "none").ToString()` *not* work?

Comment: As an aside, especially if you are in control of the code, you might be interested in the [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the proper way to check for null values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788466/what-is-the-proper-way-to-check-for-null-values)

Comment: @sll - I know there's plenty of other ways to do it, one of which I provided.  I'm looking specifically for a way to do it without creating a new variable and without calling the function twice.  The Null coalescer *could* do it, in theory, but doesn't.

Comment: @EdwardThomson - See my edit.  I don't know if sticking a MyObject in Session will cause a runtime exception when trying to coalesce it to a string or not, but I'm not using Session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BlackBear's solution works perfectly fine as it is:

```
string y = (GetMyObject() ?? "none").ToString();
```

That will *either* set `y` to `GetMyObject().ToString()` (if `GetMyObject()` returns a non-null reference) or to `"none".ToString()` otherwise. There's a tiny, tiny hit calling `ToString()` on a string, but I'd very much doubt that it's significant.

That's fine if `GetMyObject()` returns `object`. If it returns some specific type which `string` *can't* be converted to, just cast one of them to `object`, e.g.

```
string y = (GetMyButton() ?? (object) "none").ToString();
```

Having said that, I'd probably use an extension method at that point - or just do it longhand.

Comment: Casting it to object works.  I'd almost always prefer the longer form, but it's good to know that it *is* possible to do it on the one line.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you would like to use the null-safe dereferencing operator, written as `?.` in some languages:

```
var x = GetMyObject()?.ToString() ?? "none";
```

Unfortunately C# doesn't have this operator. You can do it the way you are already doing it.

This operator was [considered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2933779/61974) for addition to the language. However it didn't make it into any released version of C#.

Comment: Never heard about such one, could you please bring some example from other languages?

Comment: Yeah, that's the kind of operator I'm looking for. Good to know that it doesn't exist.  It'd certainly have my vote for inclusion, if I had a vote.

Answer (score 0):

What's missing in code can [usually] be added:

```
private static object SafeToString( object obj, string defaultString = "none" )
{
    return obj != null ? obj.ToString() : defaultString;
}
```

Comment: Caution with this approach of an Object Extension hiding nulls.  If used excessively you can actually hide bugs and lead to more/bad code.  I love extensions, just keep this in mind when using one like this.