# What's the best implementation of safe navigation operator

Tags: c#, nullpointerexception

Is there an operator in C# that behaves like the safe navigation operator in groovy?

For instance, in groovy, doing something like this will prevent it from getting a NullPointerException if SessionData.CurrentSeminar is null.

```
int respId = SessionData.CurrentSeminar?.SeminCbaRespId;
```

How is this accomplished with C#?

Comment: You haven’t mentioned which value you want if CurrentSeminar is null. Do you want null or 0?

Comment: It's worth noting that C# 6.0 added the safe navigation operator that works like in the questions example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That operator does not exist in C#. You could do it with an inline-if

```
int respId = SessionData.CurrentSeminar != null ? 
   SessionData.CurrentSeminar.SeminCbaRespId : default(int);
```

or as an extension method.

```
var respId = SessionData.CurrentSeminar.GetSeminCbaRespId();

public static int GetSeminCbaRespId(this typeofCurrentSeminar CurrentSeminar)
{
   return CurrentSeminar != null ? CurrentSeminar.SeminCbaRespId : default(int);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a good workaround, thanks. It's weired that such a perfect operator does not exist in C#.

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/192177/a-bit-more-c-syntactic-sugar-for-nulls

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2081709/33080 - it’s Eric’s standard answer. We want this, but we can’t implement everything due to time constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe workaround like this?

```
int respId= ReferenceEquals(SessionData.CurrentSeminar,null)?-1:SessionData.CurrentSeminar.SeminCbaRespId;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no operator for this, but you can get close. Try the one from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9825511/33080):

```
int respId = SessionData.CurrentSeminar.NullOr(s => s.SeminCbaRespId) ?? 0;
```

This gets extra useful if you need to chain several of them:

```
var elem = xml.Element("abc")
    .NullOr(x => x.Element("def"))
    .NullOr(x => x.Element("blah");
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest operator is `?:`, but it's not as sugary.
So, you could do:

```
int respId = SessionData.CurrentSeminar != null ? SessionData.CurrentSeminar.SeminCbaRespId : 0; // if 0 is the "null" value
```