# Short version for Initialize a variable

Tags: c#

I would like to refactor the following 2 lines of code:

```
var myDbObject = service.GetObj(id);
name = myDbObject != null ? myDbObject.Name : "No name";
```

How can I avoid using the auxiliar variable "myDbObject"?

Can I do this with only one line of code?

Is there any way of LINQ or something else to acomplish this?

**Solutions that I am not looking:**

- using a service that returns the Name and not the full object;
- calling the service more than one time.

Comment: The null ternary (`??`)?

Comment: @ColeJohnson null ternary will assign myDbObject. Dry needs to assign it to myDbObject.Name

Comment: @ColeJohnson are you telling me to use service.GetObj(id).Name ?? "No name" >> that will not work everytime the object is null I will have an exception when I access the property Name of a null.

Comment: @Dryadwoods what are you trying to achieve by not using the variable. Your option is using a try catch but Don't please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deep Null checking, is there a better way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080647/deep-null-checking-is-there-a-better-way)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var name= service.GetObj(id)==null? "No name": service.GetObj(id).Name;
```

Comment: No, that is not a solution since you are calling the service 2 times and I do not want to do that.

Comment: @Dryadwoods - well that's a new constraint that you just introduced that wasn't mentioned in the question, so I'm going to +1 this answer. It's usually best to be clear on all constraints that you want to apply.

Comment: @Dryadwoods, possibly impossible. Shall wait other's response.