# Pattern for chaining together calls that take in Options

Tags: scala

I'm finding that I often have to chain together functions that work on an `Option` and return a different `Option` that look something like this:

```
if(foo.isDefined) someFunctionReturningOption(foo.get) else None
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? This pattern gets quite verbose with more complicated variables.

I'm seeing it a fair bit in form handling code that has to deal with optional data. It'll insert `None` if the value is `None` or some transformation (which could potentially fail) if there is some value.

This is very much like [the `?.` operator proposed for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2081709/1968462).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `flatMap`:

```
foo.flatMap(someFunctionReturningOption(_))
```

Or in a for-comprehension:

```
for {
    f <- foo
    r <- someFunctionReturningOption(f)
} yield r
```

The for-comprehension is preferred when chaining multiple instances of these functions together, as they de-sugar to `flatMap`s.

Answer (score 4):

There're a lot of options (pun intended) but for comprehensions, I guess, is the most convinient in case of chains

```
for { 
  x <- xOpt
  y <- someFunctionReturningOption(x)
  z <- anotherFunctionReturningOption(y)
} yield z
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `flatMap`:

```
foo.flatMap(someFunctionReturningOption)
```

This fits into the general monadic structure, where a monad wrapping a type uses `flatMap` to return the same type (e.g. `flatMap` on `Seq[T]` returns a `Seq`).

Answer (score 2):

`Option` supports map() so when `x` is an `Option[Int]` this construct:

```
if (x.isDefined)
  "number %d".format(x.get)
else
  None
```

is easier to write as:

```
x map (i => "number %d".format(i))
```

map will keep `None` unmodified, but it will apply the function you pass to it to any value, and wrap the result back into an Option. For example note how 'x' gets converted to a string message below, but 'y' gets passed along as `None`:

```
scala> val x: Option[Int] = Some(3)
x: Option[Int] = Some(3)

scala> val y: Option[Int] = None
y: Option[Int] = None

scala> x map (i => "number %d".format(i))
res0: Option[String] = Some(number 3)

scala> y map (i => "number %d".format(i))
res1: Option[String] = None
```