# NullReferenceException when using Null-conditional Operator with object initializer

Tags: c#, .net

Why I get `System.NullReferenceException` running a code like:

```
var Response = new Response()
{
    Id = request?.Event.Id
};
```

Shouldn't I just get Null value for Id property (Id is a string)?

Comment: What happens if you use `request?.Event?.Id`?

Comment: @mjwills well that works, but why I have to use question mark everywhere? Shouldn't it stop executing the statement on first null?

Comment: Your current code only take into account if `request` is `null` and `Event` will not be returned if that was the case. If `Event` is `null` in the `request` instance then that would still lead to an NRE when you try to access the `Id` property.

Comment: @Igor Ok, I'll walk myself out... Apparently, I stay at work to long. I see my obvious mistake now :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080647/deep-null-checking-is-there-a-better-way would likely be a 'better' duplicate than the one that was chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code only take into account if `request` is `null` and `Event` will not be returned if that was the case. If `Event` is `null` in the `request` instance then that would still lead to an NRE when you try to access the `Id` property.

The fix is to also add the null conditional operator to `Event` which will return `null` if `Event` is null and not try to access `Id`.

```
request?.Event?.Id
```